# Is my proof of the tensor identity true?

Tags: tensors

If $F^{\alpha \beta} = -F^{\beta \alpha}$ (i.e. anti-symmetric) then prove the following:

$F^{\alpha}_{\mu,\nu} F^{\nu}_{\alpha} = - F_{\mu\alpha,\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$

My proof is as follows (where $g_{\sigma\rho}$ is the metric),
\begin{align*}
F^{\alpha}_{\mu,\nu} F^{\nu}_{\alpha} &= \frac{\partial g^{\alpha\beta} F_{\mu\beta}}{\partial x^{\nu}}F^{\nu}_{\alpha} \\
&= \frac{\partial F_{\mu\beta}}{\partial x^{\nu}}g^{\alpha\beta} F^{\nu}_{\alpha} \\
&= \frac{\partial F_{\mu \beta}}{\partial x^{\nu}}F^{\beta \nu}\\
&= -F_{\mu \beta,\nu}F^{\nu\beta}
\end{align*}

My main concern is whether or not I can just move the metric out of the derivative like that, as well as my indices having different labels to the identity (i.e. I didn't change $\nu$ to $\beta$ in the partial derivative)?

Comment: the metric tensor is parallel, i.e. it's covariant derivative vanishes, but not the partial derivatives. So no.

Comment: in addition, $F_{\mu, \nu} $ is not $\frac{\partial F_\mu}{\partial F^\nu}$ but  $\frac{\partial F_\mu}{\partial x^\nu}$ for some choice of coordinates $(x^\alpha)$

Comment: Oh I see, so I shouldn't use $F^{\alpha}_{\mu} = g^{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\beta}$?

Comment: that's the definition, you have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I worked through the problem a few more times and this is my new answer,

$\begin{align}
F_{\mu,\nu}^{\alpha}F_{\alpha}^{\nu} &= \frac{\partial g^{\alpha \sigma} F_{\sigma\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} \\
&= g^{\alpha \sigma}_{,\nu}F_{\sigma\mu}g_{\sigma\alpha}F^{\nu\sigma} + g^{\alpha \sigma}F_{\sigma\mu,\nu}F^{\nu\sigma}g_{\sigma\alpha}
\end{align}$

but if the metric is constant (e.g. the Minkowski metric) then its derivative is zero thus,

$=g_{\sigma\alpha}g^{\alpha \sigma}F_{\sigma\mu,\nu}F^{\nu\sigma}$

Since the metrics become the identity matrix, and since the tensor $F$ is anti-symmetric,

$=-F_{\sigma\mu,\nu}F^{\sigma\nu}$